# Microsoft Azure Web サイトの MIME マッピング のデフォルト設定を知りたい

Tags: azure, mime

Microsoft Azure の Web サイトに ASP.NET の Web アプリをデプロイしたところ、.svg ファイルが見れませんでした。
[こちら](http://qiita.com/usaribbon/items/373657884d3527786162)に書いてある内容を参考にして ルートディレクトリの web.config に

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

MIME タイプのマッピングを追加すると見れるようになりました。
.html や .txt などは特に追加しなくても見れますのでデフォルトの設定があると思いますが、デフォルトの設定はどのようにすれば確認できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

デフォルトの MIME マップは applicationHost.config というファイルに設定されていますが、直接 FTP などでは確認できないので Kudu を使う必要があります。

1/7 時点のデフォルトを引っ張ってきたので参考までにどうぞ。

```
<staticContent lockAttributes="isDocFooterFileName">
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".323" mimeType="text/h323" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".aaf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".aca" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".accdb" mimeType="application/msaccess" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".accde" mimeType="application/msaccess" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".accdt" mimeType="application/msaccess" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".acx" mimeType="application/internet-property-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".afm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ai" mimeType="application/postscript" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".aif" mimeType="audio/x-aiff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".aifc" mimeType="audio/aiff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".aiff" mimeType="audio/aiff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".application" mimeType="application/x-ms-application" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".art" mimeType="image/x-jg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".asd" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".asf" mimeType="video/x-ms-asf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".asi" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".asm" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".asr" mimeType="video/x-ms-asf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".asx" mimeType="video/x-ms-asf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".atom" mimeType="application/atom+xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".au" mimeType="audio/basic" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".avi" mimeType="video/x-msvideo" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".axs" mimeType="application/olescript" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".bas" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".bcpio" mimeType="application/x-bcpio" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".bin" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".bmp" mimeType="image/bmp" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".c" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".cab" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".calx" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-office.calx" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".cat" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-pki.seccat" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".cdf" mimeType="application/x-cdf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".chm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".class" mimeType="application/x-java-applet" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".clp" mimeType="application/x-msclip" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".cmx" mimeType="image/x-cmx" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".cnf" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".cod" mimeType="image/cis-cod" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".cpio" mimeType="application/x-cpio" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".cpp" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".crd" mimeType="application/x-mscardfile" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".crl" mimeType="application/pkix-crl" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".crt" mimeType="application/x-x509-ca-cert" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".csh" mimeType="application/x-csh" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".csv" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".cur" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dcr" mimeType="application/x-director" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".deploy" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".der" mimeType="application/x-x509-ca-cert" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dib" mimeType="image/bmp" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dir" mimeType="application/x-director" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".disco" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/x-msdownload" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll.config" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dlm" mimeType="text/dlm" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".doc" mimeType="application/msword" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".docm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".docx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dot" mimeType="application/msword" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dotm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dotx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dsp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dtd" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dvi" mimeType="application/x-dvi" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dwf" mimeType="drawing/x-dwf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dwp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dxr" mimeType="application/x-director" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".eml" mimeType="message/rfc822" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".emz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".eps" mimeType="application/postscript" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".etx" mimeType="text/x-setext" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".evy" mimeType="application/envoy" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".exe" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".exe.config" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".fdf" mimeType="application/vnd.fdf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".fif" mimeType="application/fractals" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".fla" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".flr" mimeType="x-world/x-vrml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".flv" mimeType="video/x-flv" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".gif" mimeType="image/gif" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".gtar" mimeType="application/x-gtar" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".gz" mimeType="application/x-gzip" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".h" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".hdf" mimeType="application/x-hdf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".hdml" mimeType="text/x-hdml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".hhc" mimeType="application/x-oleobject" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".hhk" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".hhp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".hlp" mimeType="application/winhlp" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".hqx" mimeType="application/mac-binhex40" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".hta" mimeType="application/hta" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".htc" mimeType="text/x-component" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".htm" mimeType="text/html" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".htt" mimeType="text/webviewhtml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".hxt" mimeType="text/html" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ics" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ief" mimeType="image/ief" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".iii" mimeType="application/x-iphone" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".inf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ins" mimeType="application/x-internet-signup" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".isp" mimeType="application/x-internet-signup" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".IVF" mimeType="video/x-ivf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jar" mimeType="application/java-archive" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".java" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jck" mimeType="application/liquidmotion" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jcz" mimeType="application/liquidmotion" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jfif" mimeType="image/pjpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpb" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpe" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpeg" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="application/x-javascript" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jsx" mimeType="text/jscript" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".latex" mimeType="application/x-latex" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".lit" mimeType="application/x-ms-reader" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".lpk" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".lsf" mimeType="video/x-la-asf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".lsx" mimeType="video/x-la-asf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".lzh" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".m13" mimeType="application/x-msmediaview" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".m14" mimeType="application/x-msmediaview" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".m1v" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".m3u" mimeType="audio/x-mpegurl" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".man" mimeType="application/x-troff-man" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".manifest" mimeType="application/x-ms-manifest" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".map" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mdb" mimeType="application/x-msaccess" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mdp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".me" mimeType="application/x-troff-me" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mht" mimeType="message/rfc822" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mhtml" mimeType="message/rfc822" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mid" mimeType="audio/mid" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".midi" mimeType="audio/mid" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mix" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mmf" mimeType="application/x-smaf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mno" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mny" mimeType="application/x-msmoney" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mov" mimeType="video/quicktime" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".movie" mimeType="video/x-sgi-movie" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp2" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpa" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpe" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpeg" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpg" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpp" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-project" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mpv2" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ms" mimeType="application/x-troff-ms" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".msi" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mso" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mvb" mimeType="application/x-msmediaview" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mvc" mimeType="application/x-miva-compiled" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".nc" mimeType="application/x-netcdf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".nsc" mimeType="video/x-ms-asf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".nws" mimeType="message/rfc822" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ocx" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".oda" mimeType="application/oda" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".odc" mimeType="text/x-ms-odc" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ods" mimeType="application/oleobject" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="application/ogg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".one" mimeType="application/onenote" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".onea" mimeType="application/onenote" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".onetoc" mimeType="application/onenote" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".onetoc2" mimeType="application/onenote" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".onetmp" mimeType="application/onenote" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".onepkg" mimeType="application/onenote" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".osdx" mimeType="application/opensearchdescription+xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".p10" mimeType="application/pkcs10" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".p12" mimeType="application/x-pkcs12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".p7b" mimeType="application/x-pkcs7-certificates" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".p7c" mimeType="application/pkcs7-mime" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".p7m" mimeType="application/pkcs7-mime" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".p7r" mimeType="application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".p7s" mimeType="application/pkcs7-signature" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pbm" mimeType="image/x-portable-bitmap" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pcx" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pcz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdf" mimeType="application/pdf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pfb" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pfm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pfx" mimeType="application/x-pkcs12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pgm" mimeType="image/x-portable-graymap" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pko" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-pki.pko" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pma" mimeType="application/x-perfmon" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pmc" mimeType="application/x-perfmon" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pml" mimeType="application/x-perfmon" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pmr" mimeType="application/x-perfmon" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pmw" mimeType="application/x-perfmon" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pnm" mimeType="image/x-portable-anymap" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pnz" mimeType="image/png" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".potm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".potx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ppam" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ppm" mimeType="image/x-portable-pixmap" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pps" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ppsm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ppsx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ppt" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pptm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pptx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".prf" mimeType="application/pics-rules" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".prm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".prx" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ps" mimeType="application/postscript" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".psd" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".psm" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".psp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".pub" mimeType="application/x-mspublisher" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".qt" mimeType="video/quicktime" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".qtl" mimeType="application/x-quicktimeplayer" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".qxd" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ra" mimeType="audio/x-pn-realaudio" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ram" mimeType="audio/x-pn-realaudio" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".rar" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ras" mimeType="image/x-cmu-raster" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".rf" mimeType="image/vnd.rn-realflash" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".rgb" mimeType="image/x-rgb" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".rm" mimeType="application/vnd.rn-realmedia" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".rmi" mimeType="audio/mid" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".roff" mimeType="application/x-troff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".rpm" mimeType="audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".rtf" mimeType="application/rtf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".rtx" mimeType="text/richtext" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".scd" mimeType="application/x-msschedule" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".sct" mimeType="text/scriptlet" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".sea" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".setpay" mimeType="application/set-payment-initiation" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".setreg" mimeType="application/set-registration-initiation" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".sgml" mimeType="text/sgml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".sh" mimeType="application/x-sh" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".shar" mimeType="application/x-shar" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".sit" mimeType="application/x-stuffit" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".sldm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".sldx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".smd" mimeType="audio/x-smd" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".smi" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".smx" mimeType="audio/x-smd" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".smz" mimeType="audio/x-smd" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".snd" mimeType="audio/basic" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".snp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".spc" mimeType="application/x-pkcs7-certificates" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".spl" mimeType="application/futuresplash" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".src" mimeType="application/x-wais-source" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ssm" mimeType="application/streamingmedia" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".sst" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-pki.certstore" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".stl" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-pki.stl" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".sv4cpio" mimeType="application/x-sv4cpio" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".sv4crc" mimeType="application/x-sv4crc" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".swf" mimeType="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".t" mimeType="application/x-troff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".tar" mimeType="application/x-tar" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".tcl" mimeType="application/x-tcl" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".tex" mimeType="application/x-tex" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".texi" mimeType="application/x-texinfo" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".texinfo" mimeType="application/x-texinfo" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".tgz" mimeType="application/x-compressed" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".thmx" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-officetheme" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".thn" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".tif" mimeType="image/tiff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".tiff" mimeType="image/tiff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".toc" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".tr" mimeType="application/x-troff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".trm" mimeType="application/x-msterminal" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".tsv" mimeType="text/tab-separated-values" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".txt" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".u32" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".uls" mimeType="text/iuls" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ustar" mimeType="application/x-ustar" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vbs" mimeType="text/vbscript" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcf" mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcs" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vdx" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-visio.viewer" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vml" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vsd" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vss" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vst" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vsto" mimeType="application/x-ms-vsto" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vsw" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vsx" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".vtx" mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wav" mimeType="audio/wav" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wax" mimeType="audio/x-ms-wax" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wbmp" mimeType="image/vnd.wap.wbmp" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wcm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-works" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wdb" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-works" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wks" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-works" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wm" mimeType="video/x-ms-wm" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wma" mimeType="audio/x-ms-wma" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmd" mimeType="application/x-ms-wmd" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmf" mimeType="application/x-msmetafile" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wml" mimeType="text/vnd.wap.wml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmlc" mimeType="application/vnd.wap.wmlc" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmls" mimeType="text/vnd.wap.wmlscript" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmlsc" mimeType="application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmp" mimeType="video/x-ms-wmp" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmv" mimeType="video/x-ms-wmv" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmx" mimeType="video/x-ms-wmx" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmz" mimeType="application/x-ms-wmz" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wps" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-works" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wri" mimeType="application/x-mswrite" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wrl" mimeType="x-world/x-vrml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wrz" mimeType="x-world/x-vrml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wsdl" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wvx" mimeType="video/x-ms-wvx" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".x" mimeType="application/directx" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xaf" mimeType="x-world/x-vrml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xaml" mimeType="application/xaml+xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xap" mimeType="application/x-silverlight-app" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xbap" mimeType="application/x-ms-xbap" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xbm" mimeType="image/x-xbitmap" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xdr" mimeType="text/plain" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xla" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlam" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlc" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xls" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlsb" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlsm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlsx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlt" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xltm" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xltx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlw" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xof" mimeType="x-world/x-vrml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xpm" mimeType="image/x-xpixmap" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xps" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xsd" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xsf" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xsl" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xslt" mimeType="text/xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xsn" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xtp" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".xwd" mimeType="image/x-xwindowdump" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".z" mimeType="application/x-compress" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".zip" mimeType="application/x-zip-compressed" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Kudu で確認できました。ありがとうございます。